# Joining iterators: `expected struct `RangeFrom`, found struct `itertools::Unique``

Tags: rust

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22042d3db495f2be17ca561703a57aed)

I am trying to join a number of iterators of sequences where the number of iterators is not known at compile time, and iterate over combinations of these joined iterators.

Can this be done at all?

In trying to do this I receive the errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:24:49
   |
24 |                 .fold(S.., |inner_acc, inner_x| inner_acc.merge(inner_x).unique()),
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `RangeFrom`, found struct `itertools::Unique`
   |
   = note: expected struct `RangeFrom<usize>`
              found struct `itertools::Unique<MergeBy<RangeFrom<usize>, std::iter::Take<StepBy<RangeFrom<usize>>>, itertools::adaptors::MergeLte>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:9
   |
22 | /         acc.cartesian_product(
23 | |             x.into_iter()
24 | |                 .fold(S.., |inner_acc, inner_x| inner_acc.merge(inner_x).unique()),
25 | |         )
   | |_________^ expected struct `RangeFrom`, found struct `itertools::Product`
   |
   = note: expected struct `RangeFrom<_>`
              found struct `itertools::Product<RangeFrom<_>, RangeFrom<usize>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

The code:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.10.1

const LEN: usize = 3;
const S: usize = 0;

fn main() {
    // Given some data I form this vec
    let iterators = vec![
        vec![(S..).step_by(2).take(LEN), (S..).step_by(3).take(LEN)],
        vec![
            (S..).step_by(7).take(LEN),
            (S..).step_by(5).take(LEN),
            (S..).step_by(11).take(LEN),
        ],
    ];

    // I want to form `a` and `b` by folding/collecting the iterators from the vec's.
    // (this is where the errors originates, comment this out to run the bottom section)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    let iter = iterators.into_iter().fold(S.., |acc, x| {
        acc.cartesian_product(
            x.into_iter()
                .fold(S.., |inner_acc, inner_x| inner_acc.merge(inner_x).unique()),
        )
    });
    // I would imagine `set` here to possibly be a `&[usize]` or `Vec<usize>`
    for set in iter {
        println!("{:?}", set);
    }

    // This illustrates desired functionality
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    let a_0 = (S..).step_by(2).take(LEN);
    let a_1 = (S..).step_by(3).take(LEN);
    // Both using `itertools::merge` and `std::iterator::chain` would work, `merge` is simpl;y used here to make the example nicer.
    let a = a_0.merge(a_1).unique();

    let b_0 = (S..).step_by(7).take(LEN);
    let b_1 = (S..).step_by(5).take(LEN);
    let b_2 = (S..).step_by(11).take(LEN);
    // Both using `itertools::merge` and `std::iterator::chain` would work, `merge` is simpl;y used here to make the example nicer.
    let b = b_0.merge(b_1).merge(b_2).unique();

    // Then iterate over all permutations of `a` and `b`.
    for (i, j) in a.cartesian_product(b) {
        println!("{:02}, {:02}", i, j);
    }
}
```

If there is anything I could add here please drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With some experimentation it would seem the best solution is to write a custom implementation of [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#implementing-iterator), see below:

```rust
use std::{ops::AddAssign,hash::Hash,fmt};
use itertools::Itertools;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MultiStepIter<T> {
    steps: Vec<T>,
    counts: Vec<T>,
    step: std::iter::Cycle<std::ops::Range<usize>>,
}
impl<T:Default+Clone> MultiStepIter<T> {
    fn new(steps: &[T]) -> Self {
        Self {
            steps: Vec::from(steps),
            counts: vec![T::default();steps.len()],
            step: (0..steps.len()).cycle()
        }
    }
}
impl<T:AddAssign+Eq+Hash+Copy+fmt::Display> Iterator for MultiStepIter<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let step = self.step.next().unwrap();
        let rtn = self.counts[step];
        self.counts[step] += self.steps[step];
        Some(rtn)
    }
}

const LEN: usize = 3;

fn main() {
    // let a_set = vec![2,3];
    // let a = MultiStepIter::new(&a_set).take(LEN*a_set.len()).unique();

    // let b_set = vec![7,5,11];
    // let b = MultiStepIter::new(&b_set).take(LEN*b_set.len()).unique();

    // for (i,j) in a.cartesian_product(b) {
    //     println!("{:02}, {:02}",i,j)
    // }

    let sets = vec![
        vec![2,3],
        vec![7,5,11]
    ];
    let multi_prod = sets
        .into_iter()
        .map(|s|MultiStepIter::new(&s).take(LEN*s.len()).unique())
        .multi_cartesian_product();
    for m in multi_prod {
        println!("m: {:02?}",m);
    }
}
```